# When using only drush for a migration - how is 'source files' / legacy-root defined?

Tags: migrations

I am using Drush 10.4 with the `migrate` and the `migrate drupal` modules to do an upgrade from Drupal 7 to 9.

But how do I define the source files?

With the `migrate upgrade` module this can be defined with the option `--legacy-root=http://myd6site.com` in the `drush migrate-upgrade` command. But I cannot find a way to do this with just Drush and the core modules. Am I missing something?